# Why does jquery $.get fail where .load() works?

Tags: jquery

Works

```
    $('#content').load('/in #overview');
```

Fails

```
    $.get('/in', function(data){
      $(data).find("#overview").appendTo("#content");
    });
```

The response is slow however when I console.log the data I get with the .get(), all the data shows up.

Comment: What is content of `/in` ? Is a `#content` element within `data` ?

Comment: check the request/response using your browser developer tool's network tab... see what is the returned value

Comment: @guest271314 no, #content is within parent page, #overview is in the data

Comment: @ArunPJohny it appears the full response comes through, and when I console.log the data I get with the .get(), all the data shows up, however it isn't parsed and inserted into #content well, does load() use a different parser?

Comment: can you share a sample of the response

Comment: @Serhiy Can include `html` returned from `$('#content').load('/in #overview')` at Question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `overview` is not a child element so you need to use filter and not find. Jquery filters out html, head, and body elements so their children are all on the same level.

```
$(data).find("#overview").appendTo("#content");
```

needs to be

```
$(data).filter("#overview").appendTo("#content");
```

Comment: That works! Thank you. Though what do you mean by "overview is not a child element"? It is a child element of html > body > #overview. It indeed doesn't have a parent within the body (is this what you mean?), it does however have siblings before and after.

Comment: `console.log(data)` look at what is there, you will see that jQuery scrubs away the html and body elements because that is what happens when you append those elements to a div which it does internally.